# Weighted Projective Space not $S_1$ generated

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let consider the weighted polynomial ring $S := k[T_0, T_1, T_2]$ such that $T_0,T_1$ have weight $1$, but $T_2$ is weigthed by $2$.

Therefore $S:= \oplus_i S_i$ can be canonically endowed with the structure of a graduated ring, where $S_i$ is the $S_0$-algebra of $i$-weighted components of $S$. In light of this one can also consider it as the projective scheme $Proj(S)$.

My question is why in that case the canonical morphism

$$f:S_0[S_1] \to S$$

isn't surjective.

My thoughts:

If I localize $S$ in $T_2$ I have already showed that

$$S_{(T_2)} = k[T_0^2/T_2,T_1^2/T_2,T_0T_1/T_2] \cong k[a,b,c]/(c^2-ab)$$

using Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem.

But I don't see how this information about this structure of $S_{(T_2)}$ lead me to a contradiction.

Comment: I think it's easier than what you're doing. It's just that $T_2$ isn't in the image of the natural map, which you can rewrite as $k[T_0,T_1]\rightarrow k[T_0,T_1,T_2]$